# Can someone explain this discrepancy in Air France stock price vs. Air France ADR price?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-valuation, adr

So recently Air France decided to issue lots of new shares, to raise money, making its stock price plummet on the Paris exchange by more than 60%:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AF.PA?p=AF.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch

However a similar change in stock price is not reflected by its US listed ADR, that has fallen by only about 20%:

https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AFLYY:OTCMKTS

Can someone explain this discrepancy?